# How To create an instance of Google BaseClientService.Initializer

Tags: c#, gmail

I want to know how to create an instance of Google `BaseClientService.Initializer`.  I need to use the `BaseClientService.Initializer` to create the `GmailService` instance, and then use this `GmailService` instance to create an `UsersResource` instance.

```
Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
initializer.ApiKey = "MyApiKey";
initializer.ApplicationName = "MyProject";
initializer.DefaultExponentialBackOffPolicy = Google.Apis.Http.ExponentialBackOffPolicy.None;
Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.GmailService gmailService = new GmailService(initializer);      
Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource usersResource = new UsersResource(gmailService);
UsersResource.MessagesResource messagesResource = usersResource.Messages;
```

Answer (score 1):

First go to the link bellow and open an application in your google account.
once you run the code you'll get exception for the first time, given you an address to go and enable the API in your google account.

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=super-pharm-log-notifications

```
      static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose, GmailService.Scope.GmailSend, GmailService.Scope.GmailInsert };

            static private BaseClientService.Initializer initializeGmailAccountServices()
            {
                string appRoot = null;


                    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current == null)
                    {
                        appRoot = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        appRoot = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\");
                    }
                    string path = Path.Combine(appRoot, DBConstants.GMAIL_CREDENTIALS_PATH);


                    UserCredential credential;

                    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        ClientSecrets secrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets;

                        var t =  GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None);

                        t.Wait();
                        credential = t.Result;
                    }

                    return= new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = "your application name",
                    };
            }

private static string Base64UrlEncode(string input)
            {
                var inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
                // Special "url-safe" base64 encode.
                return Convert.ToBase64String(inputBytes)
                  .Replace('+', '-')
                  .Replace('/', '_')
                  .Replace("=", "");
            }
```